# Why is it important to 'action' unused declared-variables and how can I find them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, build, output

I'm aware that in the build output that a list is produced showing variables that are unused. I have wondered though why VS would consider it useful to mention the fact that they're not used? In my mind most of them would not cause a problem, whereas I can see how ones like this:

```
The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
```

would be useful to know about.

The issue I have though is finding where these variables are as there seems to be no detail in the output that describes it's location.

Comment: Instead of the output, use the Warnings/Error list. In that you can see the source file and line and with a double click you'll directly get to the line which causes the issue. The reason you should remove those unused variables is that they're always created and consume memory. It might be just a bit in case of an exception object, but you could have instantiated more memory-consuming objects as well, so VS will generelly propose to remove them, if you don't need them.

Comment: It wants to save you redundant allocations.

Comment: If you don't use a var, please remove it. That's the reason why VS warn you

Comment: An unused variable is at least clutter, and may point to an error in your code.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh - no, they won't consume any memory at all. Unused means the Jitter is free to eliminate them.

Comment: I noticed that on some of them it says that it exists but is never used when it is in fact used. If you click on the object it highlights the other instances where it is used on the page and if I remove it then I get an error because it hasn't been declared.

Comment: @connersz There are two variants: Completely unused variables, and variables, which you just assign values but never use them. So of course, it will not compile, if you remove the declaration, because you assigned values to it or to properties of it, but if you never use the variable or its properties, it will give you a warning too.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh Thanks that makes sense.